# why the table of information_schema is damaged?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I want to get information from `COLUMNS` of `information_schema`. I execute the following command:

```
root:information_schema> select * from COLUMNS;
```

but it occur the  error：

> ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_11b6_0.MYI'; try to repair it

So I want to repair the table. I execute the following command:

```
root:information_schema> repair table COLUMNS;
```

but it occur error again,the wrong content follow：

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

I don't why the root user have no privileges to repair the table

Comment: I don't think it meant that `COLUMNS` table itself is corrupted; it could be any of the tables in your schema.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA contains views, not tables, so they don't need to be repaired.

Comment: A few questions: Do you have sufficient free space in the directory identified by `show variables like 'tmpdir';`?  If so, can you `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;`?  If not, can you `SELECT table_name, table_schema FROM information_schema.tables;`?  If so, can you `SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.columns;`?  In some cases with information_schema, the specific columns you select determines how deep into the internals the queries reach, so we need to get as close to that line without going over to try to pinpoint where to look next, if possible.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Thank you!It is my 'tmpdir' hava no sufficient free space..

Answer (score 2):

When you see something like '/tmp/#sql_XXXXX_X.MYI', the problem is your file system is full and the temporary file needing to be created can't be written to. Remove any unnecessary files and try again.